# VLC library at Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to publish my project and it goes fine. The installation is going fine too. But when I open the software I've got a lot of errors at VLC libraries saying that it couldn't find it.
The missing files:

- libmemcpy3dn_plugin.dll
- libaccess_http_plugin.dll
- libaout_directx_plugin.dll
- libaout_file_plugin.dll
- libfluidsynth_plugin.dll
- libi420_rbg_mmx_plugin.dll
- libmemcpymmx_plugin.dll
- libmemcpymmxext_plugin.dll
- libmsn_plugin.dll
- libi420_rbg_sse2_pugin.dll
- libosdmenu_plugin.dll
- libpanoramix_plugin.dll
- libwscale_plugin.dll
- libdirectx_plugin.dll
  After all the errors, the softwares works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about your plugin or lib file. Please download the lastest lib folder from link and change all .dll file. I think it ll work.

[Download the lib](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/tree/master/lib)